# Extract IP Address with grep

Tags: search, logging, grep

I have outputted the IPTables log to another log file,

```
/var/log/iptableftp.log
```

Within that file it displays the full iptables log line, Is there a way to search the /var/log/iptableftp.log file I previously made and search for SRC= and removing everything thats before and after and just leaving the IP address behind?

Comment: Yes, but not with grep...

Comment: Yes. Post a [mcve] and we can help you.

Comment: Without samples it's hard to provide a solution as Ed suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at  `sed`

```
cat iptables.log | sed -e 's/SRC=([0-9\.]+).*/$1/g'
```

sed uses regex in to form: s/exp_to_find/replace_with/g

Edited to fix arg in replace expression, thx to Ed Morton

Comment: It blows my mind how anyone can remember something like that :D That command outputs the entire file and not just the specific part.

Comment: UUOC, sed doesn't understand `+` without some additional arg or esacping (may require a different sed), and capture groups are accessed via `\1`, not `$1`.